# PHP OAUTH class api

Tags: php, api, authentication, oauth

I am using OAuth::fetch() example in PHP.net ([Outh code](http://php.net/manual/en/oauth.fetch.php). The cod i use is

```
<?PHP
try{
$oauth = new OAuth("consumer_key","consumer_secret",OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1,OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION);
$oauth->setToken("access_token","access_token_secret");

$oauth->fetch("http://photos.example.net/photo?file=vacation.jpg");

$response_info = $oauth->getLastResponseInfo();
header("Content-Type: {$response_info["content_type"]}");
echo $oauth->getLastResponse();
} catch(OAuthException $E) {
 echo "Exception caught!\n";
}?>
```

The Error message is

Fatal error: Class 'OAuth' not found in C:\wamp\www\Jesvin\MyTest1\test1.php on line 3

Answer (score 3):

You do not have the OAuth class available to use. It is a php extension and not part of the core package, you will need to install it manually into wamp. First thing to do is check whether the extension is available but not loaded.

Your php extension library will be something like /path/to/wamp/**php/ext** (i do not use wamp so you will have to google for your path or look for yourself in your filesystem).

If you see an oauth extension, you can skip installing oauth, if you do not you need to get a precompiled dll, look here: http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ and seach for "oauth", there are 2 (not sure which one you should use, so pick one, and if it doesnt work try the other).

Download it and stick teh dll in your extensions directory along with teh other php extensions.

Then find your php.ini file (you can use a file with `<?php phpinfo; ?>` and load it in your browser to see where php.ini is). Find where the extensions are defined and either uncomment or add this line to your php.ini file

`extension=php_oauth.dll`

ensure the dll name in the code above is teh same as the one you downloaded and installed to the extension folder. Also make sure there is **NO** semi colon at the start of this line.

That should just about do it. Hopefully php will load the DLL fine and it will work. Using pre-comiled dll's doesn't always work, but in this instance it will hopefully work.

Comment: Any alternative if you don't have access to install anything in your host server? An external library to run OAuth for example?

Comment: @samyb8 There are some pure PHP implementations that are just PHP classes, but most are oAuth1 rather than the oAuth2 you will probably want. Most of the oAuth classes stopped being maintained once the "official" extension was stable e.c.t. However you could always try google, i can't vouch for the code as i've never used it, but i found this: https://github.com/fkooman/php-oauth-client