# Looking for OAuth DLL for Windows 7 (Need to use from PHP on WAMP Server)

Tags: php, windows-7, oauth, 64-bit, wamp

I have been struggling with this problem for several weeks now and would really appreciate any help.

I need an OAuth library which works with WAMP Server installed in a Windows 7 (64-bit) environment. I want to access this library from PHP.

There are 2 OAuth libraries (i.e., DLLs) available for Windows at http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ but both are not working for me possible because they are meant to be used only in a 32-bit Windows environment.

Some more pointers mentioned at https://www.php.net/oauth are also not helpful because they only talk about UNIX environment.

Can someone please help me with a 64-bit version of OAuth library to be used in 64-bit Windows environment?

Thanks a bunch.
Su

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have several suggestions :

- if the "target" architecture wont be a windows one ; why dont you use directly the same architecture for your development ? Thus you will avoid to loose a lot of time to try to compile this dll on your computer, wont you ?
- if the target is windows, may be you could check all the existing PHP OAuth classes provided here and there for example :

  - https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth
  - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.oauth.introduction.html

Hope this could help

Regards

Comment: A person asked for help finding php_oauth.dll Recommending to use something else instead is not an answer. the pecl extension is a standard compliant oauth library, the twitteroauth is php script, far less efficient that compiled library and was written specifically for Twitter API, may or may not work for other oauth apis.

Comment: So what can I do to get an oauth lib for Windows 7 64 bit? Why does the 32 bit dll not work for 64 bit os? I thought 64 bit is down compaatible?

Comment: I use php 5.4. (addition to my comment)