# PHP OAUTH: errors on wampserver after installing

Tags: php, oauth, wampserver

I have these strange errors after installing php_oauth.dll and php_oauth does not even work on my wampserver.

The first error when I start my wampserver,

[image]

Then follows with another,

[image]

But I have php_oauth loaded as an extension as it shown in my wampserver. please check out another question of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274976/php-oauth-loaded-but-class-oauth-still-not-found-on-wampserver) too.

did anyone come across this problem before and know how to fix it?

**EDIT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Core
    [1] => bcmath
    [2] => calendar
    [3] => com_dotnet
    [4] => ctype
    [5] => date
    [6] => ereg
    [7] => filter
    [8] => ftp
    [9] => hash
    [10] => iconv
    [11] => json
    [12] => mcrypt
    [13] => SPL
    [14] => odbc
    [15] => pcre
    [16] => Reflection
    [17] => session
    [18] => standard
    [19] => mysqlnd
    [20] => tokenizer
    [21] => zip
    [22] => zlib
    [23] => libxml
    [24] => dom
    [25] => PDO
    [26] => openssl
    [27] => SimpleXML
    [28] => wddx
    [29] => xml
    [30] => xmlreader
    [31] => xmlwriter
    [32] => apache2handler
    [33] => curl
    [34] => mbstring
    [35] => gd
    [36] => mysql
    [37] => mysqli
    [38] => Phar
    [39] => pdo_mysql
    [40] => pdo_sqlite
    [41] => soap
    [42] => tidy
    [43] => mhash
    [44] => xdebug
)
```

**EDIT 2:**

**php.ini** also **phpForApache.ini** - extension=php_oauth.dll is at the bottom in the list,

```
;extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_dba.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
;extension=php_ming.dll
;extension=php_mssql.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll      
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll 
extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
;extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_phar.dll
;extension=php_pspell.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
;extension=php_snmp.dll
extension=php_soap.dll
;extension=php_sockets.dll
;extension=php_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_sqlite3.dll
;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
extension=php_tidy.dll
;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
;extension=php_xsl.dll
;extension=php_zip.dll
extension=php_oauth.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

MSVCR110.dll is the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable dll that is needed for projects built with Visual Studio 2011.

To fix this error install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable. Install according to your O.S. for 32Bit (X86) and 64Bit (X64).

And also restart your wamp server

after that paster your phpinfo().

Comment: [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) should fix it

Comment: @lauthiamkok paste phpinfo() in your question

Comment: phpinfo() returns a huge info. how can I paste it here?

Comment: <?php print_r(get_loaded_extensions()); ?>

Comment: thanks. please see my edit above. clearly oauth is not in there but it shows up on my wampserver! that's so strange.

Comment: I dont get the first and the second error anymore after installing MSVCR110.dll but php_oauth is still not working.

Comment: how do you enabled oauth ? and paste your php.ini extensions section

Comment: please see my edit above again. I put `php_oauth.dll` inside the php ext folder as per common instruction.

Comment: from where you downloaded the oauth ?

Comment: from this link - http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oauth/ I went for 1.2.3 and php_oauth-1.2.3-5.5-ts-vc11-x64.zip. as per instruction from this blog http://www.websanova.com/blog/php/installing-php-oauth-on-windows#.Ut-E4hBFCUk

Comment: I even have tried the dll from here http://pecl.php.net/package/oauth/1.2.3/windows but I went for 5.4 Thread Safe (TS) x86 bcos my wampserver is running php 5.4.3

Comment: after all of these settings you turned off all of the services of wamp server and started again ?

Comment: what the difference between x86 and x64 btw. My windows 7 is x64.

Comment: X86 = 32 bit and X64 = 64 bit. your windows is 64 bit.  now your every modules(oauth) ,php should be of x86 version.

Comment: I thought it should be x64 as my windows is 64 bit??

Comment: that's no x64 for php5.4.3 anyway. only x86 for php5.4. did you notice that from the link http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oauth/1.2.3/ ? that could the reason it won't work.

Comment: [check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000575/looking-for-oauth-dll-for-windows-7-need-to-use-from-php-on-wamp-server) and what is your current php version ?

Comment: it's php 5.4.3 maybe i should upgrade it but it is a lot of hassle upgrading it!