# Install oauth on wamp server using pecl

Tags: magento, oauth

I am unable to install oauth on wamp server.

I have tried below command and getting error so please help and let me know how can install oauth on wamp server.

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8>pecl install oauth
downloading oauth-1.2.3.tgz ...
Starting to download oauth-1.2.3.tgz (45,531 bytes)
.............done: 45,531 bytes
ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\php\pear\docs\oauth\examples
```

Comment: you can get solution from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000470/install-php-oauth-extension-on-wamp/34394855#34394855

Answer (score 1):

Under Windows you can download the compatible compiled version from here:
http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oauth/

Copy the file (php_oauth.dll) to PHP extension folder (ext)

Add: `extension=php_oauth.dll` to your *php.ini* file.

Restart Apache.